# Need to change the names of copied Excel formulas using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have worksheets named Wk1,Wk2 Wk3 etc in my workbook.

All The formulas in the Wk1 sheet are prefixed by Wk1 e.g =Wk1MonWeight

After copying formulas from the Wk1 sheet to any of the other sheets I use the code below to change the prefix Wk1 to the name of the sheet they were copied to e.g after copying =Wk1MonWeight to the Wk2 sheet the formula becomes =Wk2MonWeight. This code works.

```
Sub Step2ChangeWkNamesInFormulasOnNewWksheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Wk", 1) > 0 Then
            For Each r In ws.Range("C116:I119")
                r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
            Next r

            For Each r In ws.Range("C184:J188")
                r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
            Next r

            For Each r In ws.Range("E341:AY341")
                r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
            Next r


        End If
    Next ws

    MsgBox "Done"
    End Sub
```

**I want to change the piece of the code below so that the prefix changes from Wk1 to the name of the sheet that is immediately before the sheet being copied to + Avg**.
 e.g when the formula **=Wk1MonWeight** is copied from the Wk1 sheet to the **Wk4** sheet it becomes **=Wk3AvgWeight**

```
For Each r In ws.Range("E341:AY341")
                r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
            Next r
```

Can anyone help with this.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify: the initial formula always contains `Mon` after `Wk1` and you want to replace Wk1 with the preceding sheet's name and the `Mon` to `Avg`. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes the Initial formula always contains Mon. Yes i want to replace Wk1 with the preceding sheets name. Mon needs to be dropped and replaced with Avg so that the new formula will read as =Wk3AvgWeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, this should do it:

**Edit**

```
Sub Step2ChangeWkNamesInFormulasOnNewWksheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Wk", 1) = 1 And InStr(1, ws.Name, "Wk1", 1) = 0 Then
            For Each r In ws.Range("C116:I119, C184:J188")
                r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
            Next r
            For Each r In ws.Range("E341:AY341")
                r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1Mon", Sheets(r.Parent.Index - 1).Name & "Avg")
            Next r
         End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Done"  
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Something Went wrong: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, it didnt work. I ran it while in the Wk2 sheet and only the formulas in the Wk1  sheet changed. I have a sheet before the Wk1 sheet called Food List and the =Wk1MonWeight formula changed to =Food ListAvgWeight*12

Comment: Ok I see you're running the macro on all the sheets at once. I will edit.

Comment: Should the change also apply to sheet Wk1? change

Comment: I dont want Wk1 sheet to change at all, only the sheets between Wk2-Wk52. I would prefer though to just change the formulas of the sheet that i am currently in e.g the active sheet rather than change all the sheets at the same time as that is time consuming

Comment: Can you let me know if the edited code above in your initial answer is correct

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied I think so. But There is probablu more information needed. for now I suppose that you sheets in the WB are consecutive in position a name. That is, Wk1 is followed by Wk2 followed by Wk3 etc. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes the sheets are consecutive. they are in order  Wk1.Wk2 etc . I tried the code above but its not working either. This time no formulas changed at all. Thanks for your help with this by the way. I appreciate the time it takes to do up code

Comment: Do names and formulas change case? (Wk1, wk2, wk3mon)

Comment: No. When i need to create a sheet for a new week I copy the Wk1 worksheet to a new Tab and rename the sheet to that week so all the formulas will be identical in format. Thats why i need the vba code to change the formulas so that they are relevant for that week.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133745/discussion-between-a-s-h-and-frustrationmultiplied).